# Trouble toggling class (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I can't seem to get the `new-album` to appear and disappear. When I put `console.log("here")` in the `click` function, nothing prints to the console. However, I don't see what's wrong with the way I accessed the `test` link.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test a').click(function() {
    $(".content").toggleClass("new-album");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li id="test"><a href="#">New Album</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Photo</a></li>
    <li id="login"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content">
  <div class="new-album">
    ...
  </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: this seems to be working fine for me (class toggles). Are you using CSS to show/hide the element based on the .new-album class?

Comment: `.new-album` right now is a  blue rectangle, and I'd like for the link to show/hide it

Comment: At the moment, you are just appending the class `new-album` to `content`, do you want to toggle the visibility of the class `new-album` (that's a sibling of `content` and not `content` itself) when clicking on that link?

Comment: @Ravenous Yes, I would like to toggle the visibility of the class `new-album` when the link in the nav bar is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle an `active` class on the element you want to show/hide itself, and by using `opacity` instead of `display`, you can also animate the process.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test a').click(function() {
        $(".content").find(".new-album").toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.new-album {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: blue;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
  opacity: 0;
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li id="test"><a href="#">New Album</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">New Photo</a></li>
                <li id="login"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="content">
             <div class="new-album">
                ...
             </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just toggling a class won't show/hide you element. There needs to be CSS rules associated with that class.

This will show/hide the `.new-album` element every time the New Album link is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test a').click(function() {
    $(".content").toggleClass("show-new-album");
  });
});
```

```css
.new-album {
  display: none;
}

.show-new-album .new-album {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li id="test"><a href="#">New Album</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Photo</a></li>
    <li id="login"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content">
  <div class="new-album">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you tweaked it a bit you could still use the toggle, but add/remove a class on toggle to enable the show/hide effect. Check out the (working) snippet

Hope this helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test a').click(function() {
      $(".new-album").toggleClass("show");
    });
  
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: block;
   }
   a{
  color: #000000;
}
a:hover{ color:red;}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p{
 width:100%;
 text-align:left;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.new-album {
  display: block;
}

.show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li id="test"><a href="#album1">New Album</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">New Photo</a></li>
    <li id="login"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="content">
  <div class="new-album show">
    <a id="album1"></a>
    <p>Check out the National's new album - it rocks!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Click on the "New Album" link

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when multiple events are running on the same event. Try changing to .mouseUp instead of .click.